# Find which date is bigger(means near to current)

Tags: php

I am trying to Find which date is bigger. but here only if case goes always true.. What is wrong anybody can explain it.. Thanks in advance...

```
$str1 = "Mar 27 2014";
$str2 = "Mar 29 2014";

if($str1<str2)
{
     echo 'str1 is smaller.';
}
else
{
     echo 'str1 is bigger';
}
$str = (strtotime($str2)) - (strtotime($str1));
echo floor($str/3600/24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Convert them into timestamps so that we can compare.
$date1 = strtotime("Mar 27 2014"); 
$date2 = strtotime("Mar 29 2014");

if($date1 > $date2){
    echo "$date1 is bigger than $date2!";
} 
elseif($date1 < $date2){
    echo "$date2 is bigger than $date1!";
}
else{
    echo "Both $date1 and $date2 are the same!";
}
```